# Вывод текста HTML/Js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть кнопка "Text" и поле, нужно вписать в поле текст, при нажатии на кнопку вывести этот текст. Но выводит оно

> [object NodeList]

```
<input type="button" onclick="text()" value = "Text">
<input type="text" name="txt">
<script>
        function text()
        {
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementsByName("txt");
            document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function text()
  {
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementsByName("txt")[0].value;
                                                        // ^^^^^^^^
      document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="text()" value = "Text">
<input type="text" name="txt">
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает) А как сделать такую штуку, чтобы на самом сайте запускать код? У тебя код, дальше "Выполнить код"

Comment: При написании вопроса или ответа сверху есть панель с кнопкой вставить фрагмент кода: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIbdh.png

Comment: Понял, спасибо.